# Redirect http, https to https://www.domain-name

Tags: .htaccess

I got www ssl certificate. I've to redirect my site https://www.domain-name.com/folder/home.php whenever user typing like http://domain-name.com or https://domain-name.com or domain-name.com

I tried many ways. It's working when I type domain-name.com but it shows privacy error and not redirect while using https://domain-name.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: changed but still shows privacy error when I type ("https") It doesn't redirect to ("https://www")

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: still shows same.. [""https""://domain-name.com] doesn't redirect. shows only privacy error

Comment: may I know why it doesn't redirect when I use https only?

Comment: then I've analzed more about this and got some suggestion.. https to 'https www' is not possible. we should add SSL certificate for both

Comment: @ammni you mean, you dont have SSL cert on www?